# My string comparaison is not working with if nsis statement

Tags: nsis

NSIS is driving me crazy, I am not able to do something really straightforward.  Following string comparison with if statement is not working.  Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
!ifndef PRODUCT_NAME
    !define PRODUCT_NAME "$%PRODUCT_NAME%"
!endif

DetailPrint "TEST - ${PRODUCT_NAME}"
${If} ${PRODUCT_NAME} == "DEMO_NOT_FOR_RETAIL"
    DetailPrint "DEMO"
    File /r ${LOCAL_DIST_DIR_OUTPUT}\bin\win64
${Else}
    DetailPrint "NOT DEMO"
${EndIf}
```

Whatever what is the value of ${PRODUCT_NAME}, it enters in the if statement.  PRODUCT_NAME is a environment variable set by my shell script just  before calling my nsis script

**EDIT**
As suggested by Anders, I tried (learnt) to use variables instead of define :

```
Var /Global PRODUCT_NAME
StrCpy $PRODUCT_NAME "$%PRODUCT_NAME%"

DetailPrint "TEST - $PRODUCT_NAME"
${If} $PRODUCT_NAME == "DEMO_NOT_FOR_RETAIL"
    DetailPrint "DEMO"
    File /r ${LOCAL_DIST_DIR_OUTPUT}\bin\win64
${Else}
    DetailPrint "NOT DEMO"
${EndIf}
```

Unfortunaly, does not work.  See traces :

```
 Var: "PRODUCT_NAME"
StrCpy $PRODUCT_NAME "sdk" () ()
DetailPrint: "TEST - $PRODUCT_NAME"
!insertmacro: _If
!insertmacro: _PushLogic
!insertmacro: _PushScope
!define: "_Logic"="_LogicLib_Label_53"
!insertmacro: end of _PushScope
!insertmacro: _IncreaseCounter
!define: "_LOGICLIB_COUNTER"="53"
!undef: "LOGICLIB_COUNTER"
!define: "LOGICLIB_COUNTER"="54"
!undef: "_LOGICLIB_COUNTER"
!insertmacro: end of _IncreaseCounter
!insertmacro: end of _PushLogic
!define: "_LogicLib_Label_53If"=""
!define: "_LogicLib_Label_53Else"="_LogicLib_Label_54"
!insertmacro: _IncreaseCounter
!define: "_LOGICLIB_COUNTER"="54"
!undef: "LOGICLIB_COUNTER"
!define: "LOGICLIB_COUNTER"="55"
!undef: "_LOGICLIB_COUNTER"
!insertmacro: end of _IncreaseCounter
!define: "_c=true"=""
!insertmacro: _==
StrCmp "$PRODUCT_NAME" "DEMO_NOT_FOR_RETAIL" equal=, nonequal=_LogicLib_Label_54
```

Comment: What have you defined PRODUCT_NAME as?

Comment: @Anders PRODUCT_NAME=sdk in this case

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing defines and variables?

Comment: @Anders might be, I dont know!  I added code above.  In the case it is a define, how do I check the value in a if statement?

Comment: @Anders My traces : StrCmp "sdk" "DEMO_NOT_FOR_RETAIL" equal=, nonequal=_LogicLib_Label_54.  
I feel that it is not normal that nonequl doesn't go to the else, is in it?

Comment: @Anders StrCmp "DEMO_NOT_FOR_RETAIL" "DEMO_NOT_FOR_RETAIL" equal=, nonequal=_LogicLib_Label_54.  When my two variables are equal, it still goes in the if instead of the else.  I am totally confused...

Comment: (First trace) Looks good to me, the name of the logiclib label is an implementation detail and changes depending on the version of NSIS you are using, I am using the latest 3.0 beta. What happens if you try the code I posted? Does it still fail? Edit: Not sure about the 2nd trace, there must be something strange in your code, perhaps you change the define somewhere in your script?

Comment: @Anders See my edit.  Tried with variable, but still no luck. I thing there is a problem sith the StrCpy

Comment: If you are always going to take the value from $%PRODUCT_NAME% then you can just use a !define and !if. Can you confirm that my first example in my answer prints "NOT DEMO" two times when you run it?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a little bit strange, defines (`${something}`) are set at compile-time and you can compare them at compile-time with `!if`. If installing 64-bit things should be determined at run-time on the end users machine you have to use a variable (`$something`). While it is perfectly legal to use a define in a `${If}` statement like your example does I would not really recommend it because it adds code that will never execute.

```
!include LogicLib.nsh


Section

; Using a define:
!define PRODUCT_NAME "blahblahDEMO_NOT_FOR_RETAIL"
!if "${PRODUCT_NAME}" == "DEMO_NOT_FOR_RETAIL"
    DetailPrint "DEMO"
!else
    DetailPrint "NOT DEMO"
!endif


; Using a variable:
Var /Global PRODUCT_NAME
StrCpy $PRODUCT_NAME "blahblahDEMO_NOT_FOR_RETAIL"

${If} $PRODUCT_NAME == "DEMO_NOT_FOR_RETAIL"
    DetailPrint "DEMO"
${Else}
    DetailPrint "NOT DEMO"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

If you want to stick with the design you currently have you can actually view the generated comparison instruction and the values used at compile time by setting LOGICLIB_VERBOSITY to 4:

```
!define LOGICLIB_VERBOSITY 4
!include LogicLib.nsh

!define PRODUCT_NAME "somethingthatmakestheifstatementfalse"

Section
DetailPrint "|${PRODUCT_NAME}|"
${If} ${PRODUCT_NAME} == "DEMO_NOT_FOR_RETAIL"
    DetailPrint "DEMO"
${Else}
    DetailPrint "NOT DEMO"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

As part of the compiler output I get this:

> StrCmp "somethingthatmakestheifstatementfalse" "DEMO_NOT_FOR_RETAIL" equal=, nonequal=_LogicLib_ElseLabel_1

I still can't explain why it seems to always evaluate to true on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Anders!  The advice to separate compiler-time if's from install-time if's was a life saver!  This is a comment, not an answer, but Stack Overflow does not permit code formatting in Comments, and I am supplying a comment in case someone is Googling any of these or similar questions (as I was doing):

- "NSIS Else statement not working"
- "NSIS Else clause always executed"

I was using {If} on a compile-time define item but it was acting odd:

```
{If} MY_DEFINE:
  do_this
{Else}
  do_that
{EndIf}
```

When MY_DEFINE was defined, the above would do_this but it would also always do_that!   It seems obvious now to separate compile-time & installer-time logic but NSIS is a tool that I rarely use & I have to re-learn it every time.  This fixed it, per Anders' advice:

```
!if MY_DEFINE:
  do_this
!else
  do_that
!endif
```